# Make Sphinx quiet (non-verbose)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx through Thinking Sphinx in a Ruby on Rails project. When I create seed data and all the time, it's quite verbose, printing this:

```
using config file '/Users/pupeno/projectx/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'user_delta'...
collected 7 docs, 0.0 MB
collected 0 attr values
sorted 0.0 Mvalues, 100.0% done
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 99.6% done
total 7 docs, 159 bytes
total 0.042 sec, 3749.29 bytes/sec, 165.06 docs/sec
Sphinx 0.9.8.1-release (r1533)
Copyright (c) 2001-2008, Andrew Aksyonoff
```

for every record that is created or so. Is there a way to suppress that output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a setting to stop this - you'll want to set it at the end of your `environment.rb` file:

```
ThinkingSphinx.suppress_delta_output = true
```

In Thinking Sphinx v3 and newer, this has changed, and this setting is now managed through `config/thinking_sphinx.yml`. Repeat for each appropriate environment:

```
development:
  quiet_deltas: true
```

Comment: This does not work in TS version 3.0.5. I get `undefined method `suppress_delta_output=' for ThinkingSphinx:Module`. Any other way?

Comment: @Pioz I've just updated my answer to cover the TS v3 approach as well.

Comment: I use TS 3.1.1 and when I add this option to the .yml file, it doesn't end up in `config/development.sphinx.conf`.. I double checked and other options are reflected correctly... hm?

Comment: Hi David, it's not a Sphinx setting, just a Thinking Sphinx setting - so, it won't end up in the generated configuration file. It should stop the output of indexing though!

Answer (score 0):

Run sphinx with --quiet flag. I'm not using TS, though, so I don't know how to add make TS to use this flag. hth.

Comment: I'm not running Sphinx myself. I suppose Thinking Sphinx is running it somehow, all I'm doing is creating records. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to specify extra flags.

Comment: This is a hack but if you open RAILS_ROOT/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/tasks.rb and then on line 69 add --quiet option before --config option, it should do the trick.